# How to mock Nuxt composition API

Tags: jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I'm using the [nuxt-composition-api](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/introduction) and I would like to mock the `useAsync` function in jest. But I'm rather new to jest and can't find any examples on how to mock composition functions.
In my special case I am using `useAsync` to load content from Contentful:

```
const textEntry = useAsync(() =>
    client.getEntry<IText>(entryId)
);
```

So the mock should basically return and resolve a `Promise<Entry<IText>>`. I have test helpers to create the `Entry<IText>` part.